# Why image preview disappear when I click the browse button for ng-file-upload in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I want to show an image preview using ng file upload , it's showing the image preview but when I click the browse button again the image preview  disapper.But I want to be able to see the image preview after click that browse button again.

```
<div ng-change="chkFileExt(item.textImage)" class="button file-btn btn btn-sm" ngf-select ng-click="ediImage=true;linkItemImage($index)" ng-model="item.textImage" name="dataFile_{{key}}" ngf-pattern="'.png,.svg,.jpg'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="2MB"  ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">Browse & Upload</div>
```

Image Preview Code:

```
<img style="width: 100%; height: 55px; padding: 0px;"  ngf-src="item.textImage" class="img-responsive cls_uploaded_img img-thumbnail" />
```

Comment: what you are doing in the linkItemImage method on click of the button?

Comment: function linkItemImage(val)        {self.scope.editLinkImage[val] = true;
          console.log(self.scope.editLinkImage);
        },its just my purpose showing one div.